# Can not connect to MongoDB using PHP and NGINX

Tags: php, mongodb, nginx

I can not connect to MongoDb using PHP, the error I am getting is

```
Failed to connect to: 127.0.0.1:27017: Authentication failed on database 'abc' with username 'admin': auth fails
```

The code that I use to connect is:

```
<?php
try {
    $server = new Mongo("mongodb://admin:admin@127.0.0.1:27017/abc");
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();  
}
?>
```

I have also installed [RockMongo](http://rockmongo.com/) which can connect to the database fine.

The control panel that I am using is: [ispconfig.org](http://www.ispconfig.org/), I have added port 27017 to the firewall via the control panel so it's passing trough.

Comment: Firewall should not be an issue. It's local. Are you sure those user credentials are valid for that database? Is this possibly a new database?

Comment: It is a new installed MongoDB server on which I have created a new database with no user so the default admin/admin should work. Even if I create a user for the database I get the same error.

Comment: Default install? There is no default user. Authentication is off by default. Have you connected at all and set up authentication?

Comment: I've installed MongoDB on ubuntu, did not change any settings. Upload rock mongo (a phpmyadmin like interface for mongodb) which can connect. Created a new database (rock mongo can connect to this). Made PHP script (as mentioned above) which can not connect.

Comment: Yup. So the 'admin':'admin' is the default user and password for rockmongo interface, not mongodb. MongoDb has no authentication turned on by default you just connect as in `mongodb://localhost/abc`

Comment: So when I add a new user to system.users for e.g. database ABC the connection string needs to have this user credentials in it?

Comment: All details in the answer explaining enabling authentication

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So in a nutshell you seem to confusing the default credentials for you RockMongo UI with credentials to connect to MongoDB.

By default on installation, MongoDB has no Authentication turned on. You can [configure authentication](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/) if you so desire, and even add that configuration to your [Rockmongo Setup](http://rockmongo.com/wiki/configuration?lang=en_us#####%20mongo_auth%20vs%20control_auth%20%0D) so that it can work on a privileged user.

All details are in the links provided.

For now just connect as follows:

```
mongodb://<hostname>/<database>
```

Provided you have access from your or another machine.

Comment: You where right, feel a bit silly, adding a user to the system.users for the specific database fixed the authentication issue I had, will have a look at the link you provided. Thanks for the feedback!